# Retain comment when TypeScript compiles

Tags: typescript

Look at the code in the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=window.IsBrowser%20=%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20IE:%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20/*@cc_on!@*/false;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D;). I need comments to be placed in the result JS code to have an ability to determine browser is IE according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser). `cc_on` is a IE conditional compilation directive.

TypeScript

```
window.IsBrowser = {
    IE: function() {
        return /*@cc_on!@*/false;
    }
};
```

Compiled JavaScript

```
window.IsBrowser = {
    IE: function () {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [WebEssentials 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6), you have the option to retain comments. After installing the extension, in VS 2012, go to Tools > Options > Web Essentials > TypeScript > Keep comments and set that value to true.

Your sample works fine for me in VS2012 with WE:

```
window["IsBrowser"] = {  // I presume this came from a plugin or another script? Window doesn't have an 'IsBrowser' property.
    IE: function () {
        return /*@cc_on!@*/false;
    }
};
```

Compiles to:

```
window["IsBrowser"] = {
    IE: function () {
        return /*@cc_on!@*/ false;
    }
};
```

**Update: Although I recommend WebEssentials for all kinds of other reasons, you can do this without - see @SteveFenton's useful comment below.**

Comment: You can also do this with the TypeScript compiler using the `--comments` flag. For example `tsc --comments app.ts`

Comment: @SteveFenton Thanks - that's useful to know. Have highlighted in answer.